# Change ImageView position dynamically not working in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

I have an `Activity` that have an `ImageView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and I want to be able to move the `ImageView` inside the `RelativeLayout` and when I remove my finger I want the `ImageView` to get back to its original position.

I have tried the following:

```
mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                int[] locations = new int[2];
                mImageView.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
                //mImageView.getLocationInWindow(locations);
                mOldX = locations[0];
                mOldY = locations[1];

                System.out.println("X: " + mOldX + " Y: " + mOldY);
            }
        });
```

and in the `up` action in the `OnTouchListener` I tried the following:

1. `setX`, `setY` (not working)
2. `setLeft`, `setTop` (not working)
3. `setLayoutParams` (not working)

So can any one tell me how to do that??

**EDIT**

Activity `xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/custom_header_layout"
        layout="@layout/item_header" />

    <TextView        
        android:id="@+id/push_to_start_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/largest_margin"
        android:text="@string/push_to_start_recording"
        android:textSize="@dimen/larger_text_size"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

    <TextView     
        android:id="@+id/timer_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/large_margin"
        android:text="@string/recording"
        android:textSize="@dimen/larger_text_size"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/record_imageview"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/record_audio_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/record_audio_image_size"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/post_done" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_imageview"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/large_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/post_cancel" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
protected void initializeUIComponentsAction() {

        mRecordImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            int prevX, prevY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {

                final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v
                        .getLayoutParams();
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    par.topMargin += (int) event.getRawY() - prevY;
                    prevY = (int) event.getRawY();
                    par.leftMargin += (int) event.getRawX() - prevX;
                    prevX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);

                    if (isTouchDeleteIcon(mRecordImageView, mCancelImageView) == true) {

                        resetRecording();
                        //mRecordImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        PhoneUtils.vibrateDevice(PostAudioActivity.this);
                        FileManager.getInstance().deleteFile(mFileFullPath);                        
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                    //par.topMargin += (int) event.getRawY() - prevY;
                    //par.leftMargin += (int) event.getRawX() - prevX;

                    mRecordImageView.requestLayout();
                    par.topMargin = mOldY; 
                    par.leftMargin = mOldX; 
                    mRecordImageView.invalidate();
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    stopRecording();
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    prevX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    prevY = (int) event.getRawY();  
                    par.bottomMargin = -2 * v.getHeight();
                    par.rightMargin = -2 * v.getWidth();
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    startRecording();
                    return true;
                }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mRecordImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mRecordImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                int[] locations = new int[2];
                mRecordImageView.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
                mOldX = locations[0];
                mOldY = locations[1];

                System.out.println("X: " + mOldX + " Y: " + mOldY);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think you are actually looking for this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `mImageView.requestLayout()` **before** you set the new location. If its not working, try to call `mImageView.invalidate()` **after** you set the new location.

If its still not working, post your code when setting the position (the 3 ways you tried).